# Custom fonts, ellipsis on MultiLine TextViews, Glyphs and glitches

Tags: android, fonts

I am required to use custom fonts in my application.

Problem: For `ListViews` that contain rows with Multi-Line TextViews having `ellipsize` property set to true, I can see some illegible characters after the ellipsis. Apparently Android pads the String(in TextView) with some characters(ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK-SPACE) unknown to my custom font.

Single line TextView seem to work just fine.

What is the best way to hide these characters or remove the padding? 
Also, is there any variant of Helvetica font, freely available that would have ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK-SPACE character?

Thanks.

Comment: Mark Murphy cautioned against this: 
http://books.google.com/books?id=QdcYzuQx0DYC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=Mark+murphy+Here+a+glyph+there+a+glyph&source=bl&ots=xKaorwV1JN&sig=xT9JBUs0jBNRVjiVyOlcNHQz_w8&hl=en&ei=eqz7S_TcAsTGrAfBtPHtAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: For future reference, that character is U+FEFF, the Byte Order Mark, which Android should NOT be using the way they are.  It's deprecated for use as a zero width space.  Bad Google!  Bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to hide these
>   characters or remove the padding?

I do not know of a way to do that.

> Also, is there any variant of
>   Helvetica font, freely available that
>   would have ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK-SPACE
>   character?

Considering that Helvetica is very similar to the built-in Droid Sans, I am not sure why you are bothering embedding Helvetica in an application. Also, by definition, there is no "freely available" Helvetica font, as that font is not free.

That being said, given a font that lacks the ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK-SPACE glyph, have somebody open your font file and add in the glyph. We did that on one consulting project of mine, and it worked out well. I am under the impression that a graphic artist may know how to do this.

Comment: Do you really have to be a graphic artist to do that? Wont a good Font editor cover my naivety with this? :)
I am using Droid Sans at the moment. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If your font editor allows copying glyphs from one font to another, then you may be able to simply copy ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK SPACE from Droid Sans to your desired font. However, I have not tried this.

Comment: Just fixed a couple of TrueType fonts, copied the glyph from DroidSans using FontForge. Was a straightforward "find glyph in Droid Sans / copy / find glyph in other font / paste" process, so totally doable even if you're not a graphics artist :-)